# Loading tfrecord into Keras through ImageDataGenerator class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tfrecord

I am fairly new to keras and I am trying transfer learning here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

My dataset however is not a binary and I have tfrecord file. I can read the file in tensorflow. I do not want to feed the images as an input to the network as the input comes from the pre-trained model. How can I pass the images and labels in the ImageDataGenerator class in Keras.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone that may have this issue in the future. If the pre-train process is all correct. You can use the tf.data API to read and prepare the images for the training and the (image, label) set, can be fed to to the (.fit) method of your model.

look at this great Post to get familiar how to read the tfrecord file:

https://medium.com/@moritzkrger/speeding-up-keras-with-tfrecord-datasets-5464f9836c36